# Why is Delphi Command Line giving me a different output to the IDE?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-10-seattle

I'm having a problem with my build machine since I have moved to Delphi 10 Seattle. The build machine is producing different results to the IDE despite using MSBuild on the build machine and setting the correct configuration. It does the same thing on my machine, so it's not related to something on the machine. The differences I can see so far are:

1. Executable size is different. 39MB command line MSBuild, 35MB IDE build.
2. I get an integer overflow error in the executable produced from the command line whereas this doesn't happen from the executable in the IDE. They are clearly two different executables.
3. A COM DLL when built in the IDE is 22mb whereas it is around 59mb when built on the command line. A little further investigation shows that it is actually adding debug information into the DLL DESPITE debug information being off in the release configuration. If I set the "put debug info in a separate TDS file, I then get the same 22mb file plus a 36mb TDS file. This proves 2 things. debug information is being added, and I have the correct configuration as this change has an effect.

rsvars & MSBUILD /target:build /p:config=Release /p:platform=win32 project.dproj

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897357/why-is-the-executable-produced-by-delphi-2009-ide-different-to-that-produced-on) marked as duplicate doesn't really answer the question, it only gives a hint as to what to look at.

Comment: Is your IDE also set to build in RELEASE, 32 bit Windows?

Comment: This might also come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897357/why-is-the-executable-produced-by-delphi-2009-ide-different-to-that-produced-on?rq=1

Comment: yes, same exact config and I have compared DCC32 from the output window in the ide and what is called by msbuild

Comment: I actually asked that question...long time ago! :)

Comment: haha I did not notice that :P Maybe try to ask it on the Embarcadero Forums? https://forums.embarcadero.com/index.jspa

Comment: Have you tried building it from the command line using dcc32?

Comment: @House That's what msbuild does

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's fine...even though MSBuild does it...I would recommend doing it from a command line...that way you know exactly what MSBuild is doing.  If you get a different size executable...then you know it's passing something extra to DCC32 or picking something up from the path.  I would suspect you have different dcu's in one of the directories and the build is picking them up.

Comment: If the wrong DCU's are being picked up then running the DCC32 will result in exactly the same wrong DCU's being picked up.

Comment: But you will know what you passed to it...So you pass it what is going to the debug build...and you pass it what is going to prod build...see if you get the same thing that MsBuild is giving you.  It's like debugging an application, you try to isolate the problem.  Check for dcu in weird places like the path line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a corrupted DProj file. How it was corrupted is difficult to say. However it was clear several command line options were being set that were **NOT** in the configuration. They also seemed to be missing from the DCC32 command line MSBuild spits out, but I'm beginning to wonder if I didn't just miss them. This project was originally probably at least Delphi 6, so has been continually upgraded. To fix it, I deleted all DPROJ, BDSPROJ and CFG files, leaving only the dpr file. I then opened up the dpr file in Delphi 10 Seattle which created the new dproj file. I reset conditional defines, search paths and compiler and linker options I wanted and viola, everything is back to normal.